# Comparing arrays, sets & their elements in SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, set

I'm fairly new to coding in and I usually find answers already on here.  However on this occasion I've been trying to find a method in swift that will allow me to identify pairs of numbers, in another array of unpaired numbers within another array for example in the image attached one can see index 7 & 8 in numbers array matches the elements in numPr2...

**import UIKit**

> var numPr1 = [7,4]
>
> var numPr2 = [3,1]
>
> var numPr3 = [5,3]
>
> var numPr4 = [1,7]
>
> var numPr5 = [2,7]
>
> var numPr6 = [4,5]
>
> var numPr7 = [4,6]

```
var arrayOfPairs = [numPr1,numPr2,numPr4,numPr7,numPr5,numPr6,numPr3]


var numbersArray = [1,5,7,6,2,4,6,3,1,7,4,5,3]
```

Comment: there is no attached image, just upload it somewhere and edit the question to include the link to the image.

Comment: There is no "method" as in a built-in function. You will need to write the code to do it - show what you have tried and then ask specific questions where you are having problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wanna get this?

```
for(var i = 0;i < numbersArray.count - 1;i++){
    for(var index = 0;index < arrayOfPairs.count;index++){
        if(numbersArray[i] == arrayOfPairs[index][0] &&
            numbersArray[i+1] == arrayOfPairs[index][1]){
                println(arrayOfPairs[index])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was trying to find.